# How to group values in column in R and obtain corresponding sums from other columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have the following data, where I would like to group the `age` variable into categories, for specified ranges and consequently sum the value in the corresponding column `y`.

```
df <- data.frame(age = c("37", "41", "42", "44", "47"),
                 y = c(4.0, 30.0, 6.0, 6.0, 30.0))
age     y
 37   4.0
 41  30.0
 42   6.0
 44   6.0
 47  30.0
```

The desired output:

```
   age     y
    37   4.0
 40-45  42.0
 45-50  30.0
```

How do I do this? A `tidyverse` solution is preferrable. Thanks!

Comment: which ranges would you like to use?

Comment: The ranges would be 40-45, 45-50, and so on, ignoring any `age` before that. So the result would be 1, 2, 3, ....39, 40-45, 45-50, etc.

Comment: so grouped by 5 if above 40, but below, not grouped?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle this dynamically is to use `cut`. You can specify the `breaks` with `seq`, and you can even create a custom function to match the label format:

```r
label_interval <- function(breaks){
  ifelse(diff(breaks) == 1, breaks, paste0(breaks[-length(breaks)], "-", breaks[-1]))
}
my_breaks = c(1:39, seq(40, 100, 5))

df %>% 
  group_by(age = cut(as.numeric(age), breaks = my_breaks,
                     labels = label_interval(my_breaks))) %>% 
  summarise(y = sum(y))

#  age       y
#1 36        4
#2 40-45    42
#3 45-50    30
```

Comment: What if I would like the last interval to be ages above, say, 55? So it would be 1, 2, 3, ..... 39, 40-45, 45-50, 50-55, 55+.

Comment: @CloftX I updated mine to this

Comment: Then, change the breaks accordingly. Check the `my_breaks` object. Something like `c(1:39, seq(40, 55, 5), Inf)` could match

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of getting your desired result:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(age = as.numeric(age),
                age_range = paste0(floor(age/5)*5, "-", ceiling(age/5)*5)) %>%
                mutate(age = ifelse(!between(age, 40,55), as.character(age), age_range)) %>%
                select(-age_range) %>%
                summarise(y = sum(y), .by="age")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(age = c("37", "41", "42", "44", "47"),
                 y = c(4.0, 30.0, 6.0, 6.0, 30.0))


df <- df |> 
  mutate(age = case_when(
    age == 37 ~ "37",
    age %in% 40:45 ~ "40-45",
    age %in% 45:50 ~ "45-50")) |> 
  group_by(age) |> 
  summarise(y = sum(y))
```

Comment: With some tweaks, this is actually quite elegant.